# How to handle or prevent all Admins and users being removed

Tags: c#, sql, users

I have a website that stores all users in a database. A user can log on to the website and if they have sufficient privileges can add/delete users, as well as change their privileges.

How do I ensure there is always at least one Administrator (to create/edit/delete users) in the system or that an administrator can easily be added to the system.

Surely I can put rules in place so that the Admin can't delete himself, or other rules like that. But what if someone deletes all the users in the SQL table. The passwords are hashed so it's not as if the DBA can just go in and add a new user with Admin rights.

Do I hardcode some special username/password that automatically gets added to the system if no Admin exists?

Comment: YAGNI. Don't code for "what if". Code for things that are actually likely. If that happens - there should be backups.

Comment: How are the passwords hashed? There should be some library doing this and you could easily write a small script that allows you to generate a new password so you can insert it with SQL or write a script that inserts a admin user when needed. Otherwise of course you can always add some business rules that test if an admin is deleted and count the number of admins before doing so. But what if one of the two last admins leaves the company the other wants to delete his account and deletes his own (another business rule: no admin user can delete himself). But there should always be add ab admin.

Comment: I would argue that going an manually running destructive queries gets into the warranty voiding part of software delivery.

Comment: Please clarify - are you trying to always ensure that an admin user is in your application's user table even if someone manually deletes all entries in that table via SQL command?  Or are you just trying to prevent all admin users from being removed via your application's normal interface?

Comment: @Oded This isn't YAGNI, it happens on web-apps all the time.

Comment: @Ross - depends on the app and the people who use/admin it...

Comment: @Oded so are we just going to assume that users/admins are competent unless proven otherwise? that would same quite dangerous

Comment: @TruthOf42: No.  You're not going to give incompetent users access to your database; they can only modify things via the web interface, which should be as bullet-proof as possible.  Ideally, your admin interface should be operable by technically skilled non-engineers (i.e., people who are decent with computers but are not DBAs or programmers).

Comment: The simple solution is to never delete an Administrator user.  A normal User can be deleted.  This means an Administrator would have to make another Administrator a User for that Administrator account to be deleted.  You also prevent an Administrator from being able to make their own account a non-Administrator account.  You could just get rid of the "Delete User" and make the user inactive.  Same rules applies an Administrator can't mark themselfs as inactive.

Comment: I realize this question is old, but I can't help asking: How is the situation after the deletion of all users different than the situation just after installing the application for the first time? How do you create the first admin user in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than focus on preventing people from circumventing the system I would focus on giving users a way to right the ship. In this case is it as simple as a command line app that lets them create an admin user in a pinch?

Comment: I like this. This would mean that anyone with access to my server could make an admin account, but if I'm assuming someone with malicious intent has access to my server and can create an admin account I'm probably already hosed, right?

Comment: Pretty much -- if they have console access the battle is pretty much over. You might be able to work in some os-specific security as well like requiring the user be a member of the Administrators group if you are on Windows.

Comment: I decided to go with this approach though slightly modified. I create a page on the site that is only accessible if the site is run locally, and the only thing it does it create an admin account

Comment: @TruthOf42: If you're not doing a constraint, make sure the fix is at least as accessible as the destructive behavior.  No one should be able to delete users without also accessing that "add a default user" command.

Answer (score 7):

So, you're wondering how to prevent a user of your **Application** from deleting all of the **Application Users**, which are stored in your database on a simple `Users` table?

Implement the exact same strategy you would use for any other data-shape requirement.  Assuming you don't have a framework that can do it better, you could add a whole-table constraint on `Users` to require there to be at least one Admin user, like follows:

```
ALTER TABLE Users
ADD CONSTRAINT Chk_MinOneAdminUser 
CHECK (SELECT SUM(Users) WHERE Type = 'Admin') > 0
```

(Assuming you are using SQL Server, don't mix multiple apps in the same database, don't have replication issues to worry about, can stand the performance hit of an additional select on all users for each table update, and can't think of something better.)

Comment: Why anyone would maintain their users via direct database access is beyond me (that seems prone to error), but the OP did offer that as an example, and your solution actually prevents it.  A simple and elegant solution.

Comment: +1 When your users are in the database, a constraint is the perfect tool.

Comment: @Brian What are the other alternatives for maintaining users?

Comment: @TruthOf42: Creating a web interface which is only accessible to admins and having that web interface talk to the database.  This interface can then encode rules like, "admins cannot remove themselves."

Comment: @Brian: It's perfectly reasonable for an admin to remove themselves under some circumstances. The rule you *want* to be following is "There always has to be an admin", which a table constraint is a good implementation of. You probably want another implementation in your web UI for better error messages, as well, but you may as well make sure.

Comment: @DougM: I'm neutral.  Your existing answer already answers the OP's original question.

Comment: @Phoshi "You probably want another implementation in your web UI for better error messages, as well, but you may as well make sure." -- these days, I'm finding maintaining a map of constraint name => error message if the constraint is violated is much easier.

Answer (score 3):

I have just a rule that an admin user cannot unmake themselves an administrator.  So if Joe and Sue are administrators, Sue can make Joe a regular user, but then she's still left and can't make herself not an administrator.  Similarly an administrator can't delete or disable their own account.

Now if the last administrator forgets their password, that's a problem.

Comment: From the OP: "Surely I can put rules in place so that the Admin can't delete himself, or other rules like that. But what if someone deletes all the users in the SQL table."

Comment: @Brian - but that doesn't make any sense.  A database user with the ability to delete records in the user table also has the ability to put them back.

Comment: Not if he doesn't remember the password hashes.  The full quote, "Surely I can put rules in place so that the Admin can't delete himself, or other rules like that. But what if someone deletes all the users in the SQL table. The passwords are hashed so **it's not as if the DBA can just go in and add a new user with Admin rights.**" Is this concern a bit silly? Probably.  Does the concern at least make enough sense to be answerable? Yes.

Comment: Isn't this turning into a "but what if the user smashes the database server to bits with a sledgehammer". If someone uninstalls or otherwise trashes the DB tables, then its restore from backup, or reinstall time.

Comment: @gbjbaanb - I have to agree.  I'm not sure about the validity of the question.

Comment: @Brian - Sure they can.  If the password is hashed just generated the hash for a password you already know.

Answer (score 2):

> what if someone deletes all the users in the SQL table. The passwords
>   are hashed so it's not as if the DBA can just go in and add a new user
>   with Admin rights.

Well, if someone deletes all the users in the SQL table, you load a backup? Why are they doing such things!?

There are various ways to recover an admin account:

1. Create a regular user, then connect to the DB directly and mark them as an admin.
2. Manually run whatever SPs are run when an admin is created.
3. Create a special page (or special version of the admin pages) which can be run without admin privileges (IP restricted, firewalled, etc.), login, and use them to create an admin.

These various strategies have several things in common:

1. They require you to be a server admin or DB admin.
2. They're dangerous and hacky.  You won't want to keep them on and you'll want to make sure regular users can't trigger them.  All such functionality should be deleted (not merely disabled) by default.
3. They're bypassing authentication, but are otherwise leveraging your existing code.
4. You don't need to code them until the problem actually happens (and in fact, should not do so; unmaintained hacks tend to become obsolete quickly).

Comment: I like option 1, as I don't have to do anything to implement that solution. But there still is a problem that if someone deletes all users you can't add another user. SPs don't create the hashes of passwords, but merely receive the hash. Should I assume the user can just create a hash of a password themselves (with some tool online?) and submit it to the DB?

Comment: You can create a special page (or application) which calls your "create user" function without requiring authentication.  It can be hardcoded with the username and password.  E.g., in C#/Membership the page's codebehind would merely be something like: `Membership.CreateUser("adminhack","te^mp*pa~ss_wordfkjl;SDKL");`

Comment: You have unit tests for your code, right?  Including your password code?  So in your tests, you probably have a pregenerated hash which maps to a password you know.  Alternatively, you can always install on a different server or write a trivial program to call your password hashing library directly to get a hash, then copy it into the database.

Answer (score 0):

1. *Someone deletes all users directly from the DB*. You can simply check whether the **dedicated** / **at least one** Admin is available on the application startup:

   ```
   using System.Linq;
   using Dapper;

   public interface IAppDbInitializer {
       void Seed();
   }

   protected void Application_Start() {
       this.SeedApplicationDatabase();
   }

   public class AppDbInitializer : IAppDbInitializer {

       private IAppDbConnectionFactory appDbConnectionFactory;
       private IPasswordHasher passwordHasher;

       public AppDbInitializer(IAppDbConnectionFactory appDbConnectionFactory, IPasswordHasher passwordHasher) {
           this.appDbConnectionFactory = appDbConnectionFactory;
           this.passwordHasher = passwordHasher;
       }

       public void Seed() {
           this.CreateUser(username: "Admin");
           this.CreateUser(username: "User");
       }

       private void CreateUser(string username) {

           using(var dbConnection = this.appDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection()) {

               dbConnection.Open();

               var entry = dbConnection.Query(
                   sql: "SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM Users WHERE Username = @Username", 
                   param: new { Username = username }
               ).SingleOrDefault();

               if(entry == null) {

                   var affectedRows = dbConnection.Execute(
                       sql: "INSERT INTO Users (Username, [Password]) SELECT @Username, @Password", 
                       param: new {
                           Username = username,
                           Password = this.passwordHasher.CreateHash(username)
                       }
                   );

                   if(affectedRows == 0) {
                        throw new System.Exception("No rows affected");
                   }

               }

           }

       }

   }

   private void SeedApplicationDatabase() { 
       DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IAppDbInitializer>().Seed();
   }
   ```
2. Why not adding rules into your application so that Admin can't be deleted?