# What happened to database constraints?

Tags: database-design, relational-database, rules-and-constraints

When I review database models for RDBMS, I'm usually surprised to find little to no constraints (aside PK/FK). For instance, percentage is often stored in a column of type `int` (while [`tinyint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx) would be more appropriate) and there is no `CHECK` constraint to restrict the value to 0..100 range. Similarly on SE.SE, answers suggesting check constraints often receive [comments](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/234572/how-to-handle-or-prevent-all-admins-and-users-being-removed#comment469176_234586) suggesting that the database is the wrong place for constraints.

When I ask about the decision not to implement constraints, team members respond:

- Either that they don't even know that such features exist in their favorite database. It is understandable from programmers using ORMs only, but much less from DBAs who claim to have 5+ years experience with a given RDBMS.
- Or that they enforce such constraints at application level, and duplicating those rules in the database is not a good idea, violating SSOT.

More recently, I see more and more projects where even foreign keys aren't used. Similarly, I've seen a few comments here on SE.SE [which show](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/336250/best-practice-regarding-table-schema/336252#comment718785_336252) that the users don't care much about referential integrity, letting the application handle it.

When asking teams about the choice not to use FKs, they tell that:

- It's PITA, for instance when one has to remove an element which is referenced in other tables.
- NoSQL rocks, and there are no foreign keys there. Therefore, we don't need them in RDBMS.
- It's not a big deal in terms of performance (the context is usually small intranet web applications working on small data sets, so indeed, even indexes wouldn't matter too much; nobody would care if a performance of a given query passes from 1.5 s. to 20 ms.)

When I look at the application itself, I systematically notice two patterns:

- The application properly sanitizes data and checks it before sending it to the database. For instance, there is no way to store a value `102` as a percentage through the application.
- The application assumes that all the data which comes from the database is perfectly valid. That is, if `102` comes as a percentage, either something, somewhere will crash, or it will simply be displayed as is to the user, leading to weird situations.
- While more than 99% of the queries are done by a single application, over time, scripts start to appear—either scripts ran by hand when needed, or cron jobs. Some data operations are also performed by hand on the database itself. Both scripts and manual SQL queries have a high risk of introducing invalid values.

And here comes my question:

What are the reasons to model relational databases without check constraints and eventually even without foreign keys?

---

For what it's worth, this question and the answers I received (especially the interesting discussion with Thomas Kilian) led me to write [an article with my conclusions on the subject of database constraints](http://blog.pelicandd.com/article/115/).

Comment: I feel for you, but it seems you already know why constraints are a good idea, so there is not much to add in the form of an answer. I will note though, that lack of constraints is not a new phenomenon, I have seen it for decades in databases designed by developers without a strong understanding of relational databases. I think it is seldom a deliberate design decision.

Comment: @JacquesB: you may post an answer, since “I have seen it for decades” gives a very different vision that the one I had of a phenomenon which appeared three-four years ago (given that I have worked in IT for less than a decade, my view of the phenomenon is probably wrong). Thus, the conclusions would be very different as well.

Comment: We work with a lot of clients. And while rolling out a new version of our software is a piece of cake, updating all databaseschema's everywhere is a pain. That's why we have most constraints in software. Ohh yeah, a tinyint for a percentage is often not a good idea because percentages can be fractions.

Comment: Voting to re-open this question as it has been incorrectly closed as "primarily opinion-based" when the answers so far show that not to be the case.

Comment: @DavidArno would "Laziness" and "fundamental knowledge gap" be an acceptable answer? I know more then one programmer who treats a database as a collection of excel sheets. Where a "join" is a dirty word because "complex".

Comment: @PieterB, I suggest you too vote to re-open it, then post that answer and find out... ;)

Comment: @PieterB: *“a tinyint for a percentage is often not a good idea because percentages can be fractions”*: in this case, `int` would be a wrong type in a database which supports `float`, `real` and even `decimal` with fixed precision and scale.

Comment: Voting to re-open this question as it has been incorrectly closed as "primarily opinion-based" when the answers so far show that not to be the case. This is indeed a very good question by any standard.

Comment: The phrasing "is it just a sign of incompetence from ORM-only programmers..." etc. makes it impossible to answer. We don't know anything about the programmers in question. If you rephrased to ask if there are legitimate technical reasons to skip constraints in a relational database, the question might get reopened. As it stands, the question seems more like a rant - which might be totally justified, but is a bad fit for this site.

Comment: @JacquesB: good idea. I reformulated the question.

Comment: There are definitely cases where I would consider restricting a percentage value to [0,100] to be incorrect data modelling. While you (probably) can't sensibly do "more than 100% of X", you can definitely "need more than 100% of X".

Comment: Vatine, you can't provide more than 100% of X so it can be a valid constraint.

Comment: I'm with you 110%.

Comment: @MatthewWhited You can, maybe not in his case, but sometimes percentages are not really restricted to 0-100. A growth of 150% does have a valid meaning, for instance.

Comment: Compare the weight a bridge can carry and the legal requirement. You really want that percentage higher than 100%. This year’s sales compared to last year. Or a rule like “date of birth cannot be in the future”. And than a doctor tries to enter an unborn baby’s estimated date of birth.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It is important to distinguish between different use cases for databases.

The traditional business database is accessed by multiple independent applications and services and perhaps directly by authorized users. It is critical to have a well-thought out schema and constraints at the database level, so a bug or oversight in a single application does not corrupt the database. The database is business-critical which means inconsistent or corrupt data may have disastrous results for the business. The data will live forever while applications come and go. These are the places which may have a dedicated DBA to ensure the consistency and health of the database.

But there are also systems where the database is tightly integrated with a single application. Stand-alone applications or web application with a single embedded database. As long as the database is exclusively accessed by a single application, you could consider constraints redundant - as long as the application works correctly. These systems are often developed by programmers with a focus on application code and perhaps not a deep understanding of the relational model. If the application uses an ORM the constraints might be declared at the ORM level in a form more familiar to application programmers. In the low end we have PHP applications using MySQL, and for a long time MySQL did not support basic constraints at all, so you *had* to rely on the application layer to ensure consistency.

When developers from these different backgrounds meet you get a culture clash.

Into this mix we get the new wave of distributed "cloud storage" databases. It is very hard to keep a distributed database consistent without losing the performance benefit, so these databases often eschew consistency checks at the database level and basically lets the programmers handle it at the application level. Different application have different consistency requirements, and while Googles search engine prioritize availability over consistency across their servers, I'm willing to bet their payroll system runs on a relational database with lots of constraints.

Comment: +!1 for mentioning the elephant in the room: the false assumption that one application uses just one DB and that one DB is used by just one app

Comment: @TulainsCórdova, I thought the elephant in the room here was Google's payroll system. :)

Comment: @Machado This is genius: _"I'm willing to bet their payroll system runs on a relational database with lots of constraints."_

Comment: It is also handy to have properly constrained databases as your application code is not ACID.

Comment: Excellent answer! Have been on both sides, and can confirm this is 100% correct.

Comment: Just to emphasise the comment made by @MatthewWhited, it is not possible for applications to enforce some kinds of inter-row/inter-table constraints without performing locking and running extra queries. An RDBMS can do so at much lower cost.

Comment: @MatthewWhited I don't know, I've seen some application code corrode relationships pretty quick.

Comment: So you didn't read what I said.

Comment: I agree with @MatthewWhited here, and with that in mind, I disagree with this answer (as written). Let's say one day you introduce a bug, and the app sends two inserts at the same time when it should only send one (e.g., create a new user). I don't know if it's going to be possible to prevent bad data from going into an ACID database with an app-level constraint. This usually leads to really weird bugs that take a long time to troubleshoot and even notice. re: "as written": perhaps there's a counter to this point that's not addressed above. Or maybe I'm not seeing some angle.

Answer (score 17):

More and more systems nowadays are running in distributed environments, on the cloud and adopting the technique to "scale out", instead of "scale up". That's even more important if you're dealing with online internet-facing applications, such as e-commerce apps.

That being said, all applications that are supposed to scale are constrained by the [CAP Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem), where you have to chose 2 of 3: Consistency, Availability and Partition Tolerance (network fault tolerance).

By studying the CAP Theorem you'll see that there's not much choice, but to chose to lose either Availability or Consistency, since you can NEVER really trust in the Network 100% of the time.

In general, several applications can afford to be inconsistent for some reasonable amount of time, but cannot afford to be unavailable to the users. For example, a slightly unordered timeline in Facebook or Twitter is better than not having access to a timeline at all.

Thus, several applications are choosing to let go relational database constraints, since relational databases are really good at Consistency, but at the cost of availability.

Personal note: I'm old fashioned too, and I've been working with some really old financial systems where data consistency is a first-class requirement most of the time, and I'm a big fan of database constraints. The database constraints are the last line of defense against years and years of bad development and teams of developers that come and go.

"Est modus in rebus". Let's keep using DB "low level" consistency where consistency is a first class requirement. But sometimes, letting it go is not a big sin after all.

-- EDIT: --

Since there's a small edit in the question, there's another legitimate reason to drop constraints in the database, IMO. If you design a product from scratch, where you design your system to support multi-database technology, you may settle for the least common denominator among the supported databases, and eventually drop the use of any constraints at all, leaving all the control logic for your application.

Although it's legitimate, it's also a gray area to me, because I just can't find any database engine today that doesn't support simple constraints like the one proposed in the original question.

Comment: "I just can't find any database engine today that doesn't support simple constraints like the one proposed in the original question." Does MySQL support CHECK constraints yet?

Comment: @VincentSavard, maybe not the exact CHECK MS SQL does, but some kind of restriction it does: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/constraint-invalid-data.html

Comment: @Machado -- that's not about specific constraints, though, so much as identifying when queries include data that can't be represented in the appropriate types.  Which is a distinct improvement on the situation years ago when MySQL simply silently ignored such values.

Comment: @PeriataBreatta, on a side note, I never fully understood why MySQL was the "de facto" OSS database chosen by website developers, when PostgreSQL was fully available and was more advanced. Maybe it was easier to install, I don't know.

Comment: @machado -- I can't be *certain*, but I know that in the early days (back in the mid 90s) I tended to prefer mysql to postgres (which wasn't renamed to postgresql until later) because of a misconception that postgres didn't support SQL (its early versions didn't -- it had its own query language called "postquel" -- and I hadn't kept up to date with its development so hadn't realised that they added SQL support at about the same time mysql became available).  If this misconception was common, it's possible mysql got ahead just because of that.  And once it was ahead, network effects took over.

Comment: @PeriataBreatta that makes sense. I got Postgres after supporting SQL statements, I've never known about "postquel". Now I'm taking hours reading about it. :)

Answer (score 11):

> What are the reasons to model relational databases without check
> constraints and eventually even without foreign keys?

First let's get clear that I'm talking here only about RDBMs, not about no-SQL databases.

I've seen a few databases with no FK or PK, let alone check constraints but to be honest they are a minority. Perhaps because I work in a big company.

In my experience through the years I can say that some reasons may be:

- In the case of **beginners** or **hobby** programmers, a l**ack of modeling skills**
- **Extensive or almost exclusive use of ORMs** with no real contact with the database world
- **Absence of a DBA or other data modeling** expert on a team or small project
- **Lack of involvement of the DBA or data modeling** expert in the first stages of the development
- **Deliberate design decisions** by a part of the developer community that considers that even a check constraint that enforces that a certain column can only have `1,2 or 3` as a value, or that the "age" column must be `>= 0` is **"having business logic in the database"**. Even default clauses are considered by some as business logic that don't belong to a database, as you can see in several recent questions and answers in this very site. This developers that so consider, obviously would use as few constraints as possible and will do everything in code, even referencial integrity and/or unicity. I think this is an extreme position.
- **Use of RDBMs as key-value storages**, either for emulating no-SQL behavior of because the requierements where simple enough to be satisfied by using RDBMS tables as isolates key-value repositories.
- **Assuming that the database will always be written to by "the app"** and that nobody will ever need to do a massive data load, or edit or insert rows via a SQL client (in many cases to correct bad data the app inserted). In the best case escenario there will always be another app (besides "the app") issuing DML instructions to the database: a SQL client.
- Not realizing that **the data belongs to the business owner**, not to the app.

That said, I would like to state that **RDBMS are very advanced pieces of software that has been built over the shoulders of giants** and have proved very efficient for a lot of business requirements, liberating the programmers from the mundane task of enforcing referential integrity on a series of binary files or text files. As I always say **"we no longer live in a one-app-one-database world"**. At the very least an SQL client will issue DMLs besides "the app". So the database should defend itself from human or programming errors to a reasonable extent

In those well known type of requirements where RDBMS won't scale well, **by all means embrace no-SQL technology**. The proliferation of relational databases with no constraints, where thousands of lines of code (generated or typed) devoted to enforce what the RDBMS should be enforcing for you in more efficient ways, is worrysome.

Comment: Just saying: “age” should _never_ be stored.

Answer (score 3):

There are external constraints that drive technology decisions. There's just few situations where you have the need and or luxury of using database field constraints on a regular basis.

1. Enterprises have developers for both apps and database along with DBA, but most developers do not work in this type of environment. They do as much as they can in code. Also, some on the database side don't get involved in the business rules. They primarily are there to keep things running. They'll never push for constraints in the db. Having to deal with legacy apps, integrations, migrations, mergers, acquisitions a db constraint may be the best solution.
2. Overloading the db can create a bottleneck that isn't easily solved by throwing more machines at the problem. There are some situations where the db language doesn't handle some programming problems without a major performance hit, so you can't plan on using a constraint for everything. Stackoverflow has one database server because throwing 2 at a problem is a challenge.
3. Automated Testing - they're getting there but many db developers are late to the party along with the IDE/testing frameworks.
4. Deployment - more db stuff makes it more complicated. What happens when an update to a client's database isn't allowed because there are data that violate the constraint? Game over unless you have a way to address this. In your app, you may decide to let the user handle this as needed or instruct some admin to do it in a batch.
5. Only the app/api/service will ever write data to the database so why bother? This does hold up most of the time which is why it's not common.
6. Handling db errors is hard enough without hundreds of constraint violations to contend with if everything gets out of whack.Most are happy making a connection and getting the table name correct.

Many development teams do not want to give too much control to a db developer. You're lucky if you get more than one, so vacations are a lot of fun. Not many require absolute control over the database domain and take responsibility for every query, business rule, performance, availability, security, and what data go to what RAID. Here are the stored procedures you are allowed to execute. Have fun. Don't even think about touching a table.

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem that I have struggled with all my career (nearly 40 years) and also when writing my DBMS. A description of my end point is here: http://unibase.zenucom.com. So here are my thoughts.

1. Generally speaking most constraints are better handled in the application so that different parts of the application can enforce different constraints. eg a state code might not apply in all jurisdictions.
2. As an aside beware of %. Markups are > 100% or you go broke :)
3. Constraints are best described negatively. ie what they can't be, not what they should be. It's always a simpler list.
4. Foreign keys are always good and should be used. Fullstop. FK is one of the few semantic constructs in a RDBMS and very useful. Biggest difficulty is deciding whether to let a value dangle if the FK is removed or to use dependent rows as a reason not to delete the FK record.
5. Constraints in the real world are usually more complex than a single field value restriction.
6. Some constraints, even at the application level, work against good operations. eg aggressive date checking hides errors in apparently good dates. You need operator error to get a measure of errors in otherwise sensible looking dates.

Answer (score 1):

More often these days, people are using software (e.g. Entity Framework) to generate tables and columns automatically. The idea is that they do not need SQL skills, freeing up brain capacity.

Expectations that software will "work things out" are often unrealistic, and it doesn't create the constraints that a human would.

For best results, create tables using SQL and add constraints manually, but sometimes people cannot do this.

Comment: Some frameworks support adding PKs and FKs (semi)automatically, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Database constraints might have been a smart idea, but what about a practical use for them? Take your percentage constraint. If you apply that, your DB will happily reject invalid percentages. And then? You will need business logic to handle the exception. Which actually means that the business logic writing a wrong percentage already failed elsewhere. So in the short: the only practical constraint left are those you see (like PK/FK).

Comment: I politely disagree with this. If you really need consistency of data, DB constraints are a must, specially if your business logic is failing. They way you're describing the scenario a silent fail would occur, where the damage done by a wrong percentage failure would be propagated further in the system. If you have a DB constraint about that, you'd fail fast, and thus give the business logic developers a chance to see the error early and patch the business logic system, instead of allowing corrupt data into it.

Comment: @Machado You claim that business logic must be implemented at low level (the database). The only advantage I see is that you need highly trained and paid DB admins to program triggers for a dedicated DB you can no longer use in the next version/alternate DB. There's a good reason to have a database layer separated from a business logic layer.

Comment: I agree with you that there's a good reason to separate DB layer from BL layer. But that's not the only practical use of DB constraints, specially if you're dealing with legacy systems where teams come and go, and the only common point is the database of several versions of the software, specially for in-house developed solutions.

Comment: My understanding is that if percentage constraint is violated, you don't have to *handle* this exception, because such violation indicates that there is a *bug* in your code in the first place (either someone used a simple integer instead of an instance of `Percentage` class, or there is a error in the validation itself), as opposed to an exceptional case (such as a network connection is down). For me, the violation should led to HTTP 500 for a web app or a crash for a desktop app, and then it should be logged and fixed.

Comment: @ArseniMourzenko So you just keep on with wrong data? I say: get your business logic correct in first place, not when customers return the scrap you produced.

Comment: @ThomasKilian: nope; exactly the opposite. The wrong data won't get in, specifically because database constraints are there. If your business logic is right in code, you'll never violate those constraints in the first place. If a bug occurred in the code, those constraints will alert you about this bug, while keeping the database safe from the scrap.

Comment: @ArseniMourzenko You all argue like "lets add another watch dog to bite the bad ones" rather than making it right in first place. Strange attitudes.

Comment: @ThomasKilian: arguing? Well, I'm rather trying to understand your point, since this is exactly the opinion which led to the original question in the first place. Right now, I still don't understand it very well, thus my comments. And by the way, I upvoted your answer.

Comment: @ThomasKilian: I don't think that anybody is arguing against "making it right in the first place" - it is probably more that anybody with a bit of experience knows it is a bad idea to design a system on the assumption that you *will* get everything right the first time and no bugs or mistakes will *ever* occur during the lifetime of the system. DB constraints ensure that a bug or mistake does not corrupt the database.

Comment: @JacquesB, precisely.

Comment: @JacquesB I'm fighting against wind mills. If you place business logic in the DB it can as well fail as in the first place and not save you the same way. But (!) you now have business logic where it does not belong. Believing that the DB can save your rotten business logic is simply wrong. Logic in the DB has to follow the same rules as the whole business logic.

Comment: @ThomasKilian: If database constraints are business logic then the table schema and the data itself is also business logic. When people talk about keeping business logic out of the database, they are usually talking about procedural logic like in stored procedures, certainly not about integrity constraints.

Comment: @JacquesB They _are_ business logic. Any constraint reflects a business rule or requirement. And you need to implement that constraint. But NOT in the DB. Instead where you deal with the logic (aka programs/apps).

Comment: @ThomasKilian following that trail of thought to its exteme, DBs should not store typed data, but only blobs - because any choice of a data type actually imposes an implicit constraint that could be considered "business logic". Where do you draw the line?

Comment: @Hulk I see String, Integer, Float, etc. as primitives. Some are borderline and need to be discussed when building the business object. E.g. a zip is a number - in most countries. But UK has alpha-num for zips. You can not always just use blobs for performance reasons, I know. But you should keep that at the outer edge and not make it your prior concern.

Comment: @ThomasKilian: I think I see where you are coming from, but you should probably clarify you are talking about a very specific use of databases, where there is a single application with complete exclusive control of the DB. Even simple SQL scripting and reporting would have to be outlawed with this approach.

Comment: @JacquesB I could elaborate on the answer and make it rather book format. It's very controversial. I'll leave it as it is. It seems like there's 50/50 pro and con this short statement. I like your answer and also the article the OP has posted as edit.